# Finding All Anagrams in a String

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

**Problem**: find all anagrams in a string such that one substring can be formed from another substring by rearranging its letters. Given a string $s$, find the number of pairs of substrings of the string that are anagrams of each other.

Below is the traditional solution to this problem that uses $O(n^2\times n\log{n})=O(n^3\log{n})$.

Below at line  15, the formula is used to find all anagrams of same length:

$$\frac{count(count-1)}{2}$$

For example, if $s=KKKK$, then all anagrams of length 1 are 6 are
$$
\underset{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4}{\underbrace{KKKK}} = \{s_1, s_2\}, \{s_1, s_3\}, \{s_1, s_4\}, \{s_2, s_3\},\{s_2, s_4\},\{s_3, s_4\} = {4 \choose 2}
$$

All anagrams of length 2, then all anagrams of length 2 are 3:
$$
\underset{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4}{\underbrace{KKKK}} = \{s_1s_2, s_2s_3\}, \{s_1s_2, s_3s_4\}, \{s_2s_3, s_3s_4\} = {3 \choose 1}
$$

**Question**: All anagrams of length 3, then all anagrams of length 3 are 1 though the combination formula gives 2. Why, please?:
$$
\underset{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4}{\underbrace{KKKK}} = \{s_1s_2s_3, s_2s_3s_4\}, \{s_1s_2, s_3s_4\}, \{s_2s_3, s_3s_4\} = {2 \choose 1} = 2
$$

Also, I am not sure how we get the formula below to find the total number of all anagrams in a string, and why it's justified to be used in this problem?

$$
\sum_i{\frac{count_{anagram_i}\left( count_{anagram_i}-1 \right)}{2}}
$$

[image]

Comment: How are you using the combination formula in your example of anagrams of length 2? From what i see you have to select 2 out of all possible substrings of given length, which results in 1 anagram of length 3

Comment: @RinkeshP. Since I have 3 pairs of $KK$, I want to find the number of pairs out of 3.

Comment: $\frac{count\ast (count-1)}{2}$ is just$ \binom{n}{2}$

Comment: @RinkeshP. Thanks. Why ${n \choose 2}$ work for all cases, please? Still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines $1-12$ are pretty straightforward, finding all substrings, sorting them and updating the counter for each occurrence of a substring and its permutation accordingly.

Now, $3$ substrings $BAC$, $ACB$ and $CBA$ . Sorting them lexicographically gives $ABC$. And in the hashmap $anagrams$ count of $ABC$ would be $3$. The question is asking to find *anagrams in a string such that one substring can be formed from another substring by rearranging its letters*, so essentially **pairs of substrings**. If you choose any $2$ from $BAC$, $ACB$ and $CBA$, you would get such a pair. The total number of such pairs would be $$\frac{3\ast (3-1)}{2} = \binom{3}{2} = 3$$. Similarly the idea can be extended to find the number of pairs for an arbitrary count as $$\frac{count\ast (count-1)}{2} = \binom{count}{2}$$

All that is left now is to sum them up.

---

P.S.

The algorithm is returning the count, while the question is asking to return substrings, so instead of incrementing the count you can save the substrings instead.

Comment: Why does the ${n \choose 2}$ work for all cases, please?

Comment: @Avv can you give an example where it doesn't work? I am not sure I understand your doubt. Are you asking why ${n \choose 2}$ results in number of pairs out of $n$ ?

Comment: For example, in case we want to find anagrams of length 3 in string $KKKK$ (we will have 1). Why does the formula work in this case (not numerically, but logically)? I know the formula works for all cases numerically, but I am asking about the interpretation of the formula and why it works for all cases.

Comment: substrings of length $3$ in $KKKK$ are the first and last $3$ $K's$ i.e. $KKK$ and $KKK$, lets call them $s1$ and $s2$. To say that you have an anagram, you need to have atleast $2$ substrings which use the same set of characters. Now lets say you pick up $s1$, you only have $s2$ as a choice to pair it up with or vice versa when you pick $s2$. In any case you end up with the pair $(s1,s2)$.

Comment: @Avv https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590875/proof-for-combination-formula-n-choose-k this might help.

Comment: Why we can not just order the substring and hash it to the same bucket and increment the bucket by 1 then add all bucket counts? Why we have to use the formula ${n \choose 2}$?

Comment: @Avv because we need to count pairs. If what you say did work then for a single occurrence of a substring the count returned would be $1$, but in fact you don't have any other substring whose characters can be permuted to give the previous string, and hence is not an anagram.